# excel dump operation with cursor for loop

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

[image]

I am trying to create the above table. I used the variables a and b to return each month. I want it to print the 1st , 2nd , 3rd and 4th week for each month. I can't run my loop. What do you think is the problem?

```
DECLARE
 application OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
 workbooks OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
 workbook OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
 worksheets OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
 worksheet OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
 cell OLE2.OBJ_TYPE;
 args OLE2.LIST_TYPE;
 k number:=1;
 J NUMBER(6);
 a number(6):=01;
 b number(6):=12;
 tutar_t number(6);
 
 cursor c is 
 select *
 from muhasebe.doviz_takip;
 tutar1 number(13,2):=0; 
 tutar2 number(13,2):=0; 
 tutar3 number(13,2):=0;
 tutar4 number(13,2):=0; 
 
BEGIN
 
application:=OLE2.CREATE_OBJ('Excel.Application');
ole2.set_property(application,'Visible', true);
ole2.set_property(application,'StandardFontSize','10');
workbooks := OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(application, 'Workbooks'); 
workbook:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbooks,'Add');                                                                                               
worksheets:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbook, 'Worksheets');                                                       
worksheet:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheets,'Add');

j:=1;    

args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, J+1);
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 1);
cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'FontStyle', 'Bold');
OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', 'OCAK');
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'ColumnWidth', 12); 

args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, J);
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 3);
cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'FontStyle', 'Bold');
OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', '1.Hafta');
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'ColumnWidth', 12); 

args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, J);
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 4);
cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'FontStyle', 'Bold');
OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', '2.Hafta');
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'ColumnWidth', 12);  

args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, J);
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 5);
cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'FontStyle', 'Bold');
OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', '3.Hafta');
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'ColumnWidth', 12);  

args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, J);
OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 6);
cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'FontStyle', 'Bold');
OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', '4.Hafta');
OLE2.Set_Property(cell, 'ColumnWidth', 12);  
j:=j+1;

go_block('XDOVIZ_TAKIP');
FIRST_RECORD;

for r in c loop

    if to_char(r.varis_tar,'mm')>a and to_char(r.varis_tar,'mm')<b then    --we returned by creating and incrementing variables a and b so that it can return all months separately
    
    if  to_char(r.varis_tar,'dd')>01 and to_char(r.varis_tar,'dd')<07 then  -- we gave a range for each week and printed the total 'tutar'
      tutar1:=(r.tutar)+tutar1;  
      --message(tutar1); 
    
      elsif to_char(r.varis_tar,'dd')>07 and to_char(r.varis_tar,'dd')<14 then
        tutar2:=(r.tutar)+tutar2;
        --message(tutar2);
     
      elsif to_char(r.varis_tar,'dd')>14 and to_char(r.varis_tar,'dd')<21 then
      tutar3:=(r.tutar)+tutar3;
    
      elsif to_char(r.varis_tar,'dd')>21 and to_char(r.varis_tar,'dd')<31 then
      tutar4:=(r.tutar)+tutar4;
      end if;
      
    tutar_t:= tutar1+tutar2+tutar3+tutar4;  
    end if;

    while k=1 loop
  
  
  args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, j);
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 2);
  cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
  OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
  OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', tutar_t);
  
  args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, j);
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 3);
  cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
  OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
  OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', tutar1);

  args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, j);
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 4);
  cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
  OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
  OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value',tutar2);

  args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, j);
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 5);
  cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
  OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
  OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', tutar3);
 
  args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, j);
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, 6);
  cell:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(worksheet, 'Cells', args);
  OLE2.DESTROY_ARGLIST(args); 
  OLE2.SET_PROPERTY(cell, 'Value', tutar4);
 
    end loop;
  j:=j+1;
  a:=a+01;
  b:=b+01;
  NEXT_RECORD;

end loop;   
  
OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(worksheet);
OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(worksheets);
OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(workbook);
OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(workbooks);
OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(application); 
END;
```

When I finish the for loop at the end of the nested if cycle and enter the ranges a, b for only 1 month, my cycle works correctly. For example: a:=01 b:=03, I can print the value of the 2nd month. But I couldn't work it for 12 months.
this is my code i will be glad if you can help me,thanks

Comment: At a first glimpse, assignment those zero-prefixed values to numeric variables seems weird, and should be prevented.

Comment: i tried this. but it didn't work. Since I have defined the interval as 'dd' 'mm' in date format, this definition used

Comment: İ've just meant that an assignment like a:=0 has no sense, where a is numeric.

Comment: If it is meaningless, how does it give the correct result for a single month? I am confused.

Comment: And do you think there is another solution method?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no Forms installation available currently :)